# Update server design on C++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, asyncsocket

I am desining an update server. The general design is:

1. Clients connect to Server
2. Server initializes Clients
3. <some calculation of the server side>
4. Server sends all Clients results
5. Clients do not send to Server anything, just recieve server's update

Items 3-5 are repeated. How can I implemented that logic on C++?

Comment: May be you want a multicast client server design

Comment: @ArunMu, I'm concered clients behind NAT don't recieve messages.

Comment: hmm..maybe he can do away with some IGMP proxy.but leaving all these aside, the question is on design of server. So its not just the parameters that the OP have mentioned that come to play when deciding the architecture, there are several other things like 1) How many active connections 2) Platform independence 3) Threading details 4) TCP/UDP 5) Throughput etc..

Comment: @Alex You may want to look at Proactor pattern from ACE (see my answer) http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/examples/Reactor/Proactor/ (examples from the ACE source)

Comment: This is like a homework question, there is no research effort at all.

Answer (score 2):

The [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library provides the kind of infrastructure you may need. I suggest that you check out the provided examples for inspiration.

Comment: Can I see some examples working with several clients?

Comment: I don't have more specific pointers, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Beside [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) you can try to use [ACE framework](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html).

ACE implements many network design patterns (Reactor and Proactor for example). Though the documentation may not be enough the  [ACE Programming Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201699710) book provides a extremely good documentation about ACE functionality and how to use ACE efficiently. I find ACE to be extremely powerful for creating portable client server applications.

Comment: Is there any free ebooks about ACE?

Comment: @Alex I don't know about that. But I remember finding enough information on google. But I admit the book explains a lot better many aspects that are superficially treated elsewhere.

Comment: Note that Boost.Asio builds upon the same conceptual framework as ACE, but provides a more modern API.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti I admit never coding with Boost.Asio, I just saw some code and it was pretty easy to understand (given the previous experience with ACE). 

About the API I cannot argue with you, I usually want things to work :)